# How to fetch data from other table using a unique value from the Users table in Laravel 5.5

Tags: database, laravel

I want the **Users** to upload **many images** out of which they can choose **any image** as their **profile picture**.

The **path/name of the images** they upload will be stored in a table called `'user_images'` having columns `image_id, user_id, image_name`.

The `'image_id'` of the image chosen as profile picture will be stored in the `'profile_image'` column of `'users'` table and will be updated if user changes the profile picture.

Now I want to display the image whose `'image_id'` is stored in the `'users'` table and path is stored in the `'user_image'` table but I don't know how to do it.

Or suggest me any better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a relation on the User model to profile picture:

```
public function profilePicture()
{
     return $this->hasOne(UserImage::class, 'image_id', 'profile_image');
}
```

then later access the image patch like so:

```
$user->profilePicture->image_name
```